# SQLite INSERT statement with mixed values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to insert a record into table "SampleTable" and the INSERT statement has 2 real values and one SELECT statement. I know that I could use a Trigger to solve the problem but I need a solution that allows an INSERT statement similar to the one below (which does not work. It produces a "Syntax Error". Thank you for your help in this matter.

```
CREATE TABLE "SampleTable" (
"SampleTableID" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL,
"UniqueIdentifier" nvarchar,
"Name" nvarchar(50),
"City" nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO "SampleTable" (
"UniqueIdentifier",
"Name",
"City"
) 
VALUES ((SELECT substr(u,1,8)||'-'||substr(u,9,4)||'-4'||substr(u,13,3)||
  '-'||v||substr(u,17,3)||'-'||substr(u,21,12) from (
    select lower(hex(randomblob(16))) as u, substr('89ab',random() % 4 + 1, 1) as v),"Russel","Dallas");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select` instead of `insert . . . values`.  I think this is the syntax you are looking for:

```
INSERT INTO "SampleTable" (UniqueIdentifier, Name, City) 
    SELECT substr(u, 1, 8)||'-'||substr(u, 9, 4)||'-4'||substr(u, 13, 3)||'-'||v||substr(u, 17, 3)||''||substr(u, 21, 12), 'Russel', 'Dallas'
    from (select lower(hex(randomblob(16))) as u, substr('89ab',random() % 4 + 1, 1) as v
         ) toinsert;
```